# A matrix minimisation problem

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, fa.functional-analysis, matrices

Feel free to edit the title!

Suppose A is a C*-algebra and $a,b\in A$ are *self-adjoint*.  I'd be very happy with A being just $n\times n$ matrices.

> **Question:** If there are $t\in\mathbb R$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ with $|\lambda|=1$ such that $\cosh(t)(a^2+b^2)+\sinh(t)(\lambda ab+\overline\lambda ba)$ is a contraction, then it's possible to choose $\lambda=\pm1$ and still have a contraction (maybe for a different value of $t$).

There's obviously something in the background to do with hyperbolic metrics etc. etc. but I can't see how to leverage any general theory.  So I've asked the question in a simple, clean way, but in a way which is maybe lacking context.  The *hope* is that because a and b are self-adjoint, it should be enough to choose $\lambda$ real (i.e. self-adjoint) but I've no idea if this is true...

Comment: Yes, somebody please edit the typo in the title...

Comment: @J.M. I "fixed" the title to what I assumed is the correct spelling. I am not entirely clear on what that has to do with the text of the question, so it may still be inappropriate. 

Comment: Well, it's a "norm minimisation" problem in disguise, right.  I want to know which $t$ and $\lambda$ give the smallest norm to my cosh and sinh formula; my hope is that this occurs for real $\lambda$.